# Variance of a probability density function: exponential of scaled cosine

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

I'm trying to calculate the variance of a random variable, which has the following pdf: $\displaystyle f_X(x) = \frac{\exp\left(\kappa\cos(x)\right)}{2\pi I_0(\kappa)}$, where $\kappa$ is a fixed parameter, $I_0(\cdot)$ is the *modified Bessel function of the first kind*, and $x\in[-\pi, \pi]$.

It is simple to show that $E\{x\} = 0$. So, an equivalent problem is to calculate the following definite integral:

$C = \displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^2\exp\left(\kappa\cos(x)\right)dx$.

Any clues?

(By the way, we already know that $\displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp\left(\kappa\cos(x)\right)dx = 2\pi I_0(\kappa)$, if that might be useful for the solution.)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$? For $\kappa=1$, Mathematica returns $\simeq 25$. (Before renormalization by $I_0$)

Comment: You're right. The integration bounds are from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, as corrected above.

Comment: Matlab doesn't seem to find it. Does it return a solution in Mathematica? The PDF has a sort of bell shape very close to a Gaussian. I didn't find it in Abramowitz and Stegun (Handbook of Mathematical Functions), either.

Comment: No, Mathematica gave up.

Comment: Thanks. Any clues are helpful....

Comment: I don't know how Matlab's and Mathematica's solver work. If they give up, does it mean that none of the classical integration solving methods are applicable to this problem? For instance, iteratively using the "by parts" integration or other known techniques.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the range of $\kappa$ ?

Comment: $\kappa$ is an arbitrary parameter. We can assume it positive if needed.